# Juju openstack keystone charm not found

Tags: cloud, juju, openstack

I'm trying to install openstack using juju on my local machine to test.

I'm following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Deploying_Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_Juju)

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
juju deploy --config=openstack.cfg keystone
2012-05-10 16:19:14,494 INFO Searching for charm cs:precise/keystone in charm store Error processing 'cs:precise/keystone': entry not found
2012-05-10 16:19:15,116 ERROR Error processing 'cs:precise/keystone': entry not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Keystone hasn't been officially added to the juju charm store. You can look here:

http://jujucharms.com/

I went ahead and opened a bug to get the charm into the store, as it actually has been written and in existence for quite a while.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+bug/998241

You can use the one suggested there with

```
juju deploy cs:~charmers/precise/keystone
```